# Hurt: to feel pain in part of your body

Tags: word-usage

Hurt: to feel pain in part of your body

Can I say ‘this pain really hurts in my back’ instead of ‘my back hurts’?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q. Can I say ‘this pain really hurts in my back’ instead of ‘my back hurts’?

A. No you cannot because the pain does not hurt, it is the back that hurts. Pain is a symptom of the back being hurt.

> **‘My back really hurts!’**

> **My back is really painful**

---

**hurt;** verb: to feel pain in a part of your body, or to injure someone or cause them pain. Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hurt)

**pain;** noun [ C or U ]; a feeling of physical suffering caused by injury or illness. Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pain)